# Need an advanced RichTextBox which is just the same as Microsoft Word uses

Tags: c#, richtextbox

First of all, I've searched like all the forums in internet and haven't found my ideal answer, SO before you mark it as duplicate question plz read the question.

We're creating an application which contains a simple visual studio RichTextBox.
The problem is it's too simple for our application and we need an advanced one!
So we tried some advanced components such as Telerik, DevComponents and ComponentOne enhanced RichTextBoxes,
But they don't seem to be our ideal control! and we REALLY need a RichTextBox which be just the same as the one Microsoft Word uses it.
For example: The Righ-To-Left capability for some languages like hebrew and arabic, creating tables, and an approperiate Paste function was some of the lacks which are in those components.

So we're desperately asking for your suggestion about an advanced RichTextBox component that offers just the same capabilities as the one Microsoft office uses and we'd appreciate your help.

**EDIT:
I solved my problem by using `EDOffice Viewer Component` 
Anyways, by closing this Question, you just ignored what u couldn't answer. n u could just admit that u weren't expert enough to answer this!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use microsoft word itself in your application. You can embed word document itself on the windows form, but required word to be installed in all the PCs where your application is running.

The other solution is, you can browser control. You can use jQuery and any jQuery rich textbox plugins which suits your needs.

Comment: How Can i embed word document? n it probably adds the whole word GUI there. but i just need the richtextbox control!

Comment: You can just make only word document visible and formatting controls visible, looking into office automation in C# (Office interop). But it is bit difficult, it is not a good solution if you want to save text into the database. I suggest to embed browser control and use jQuery plugin for rich formatting.

Comment: Can u embed a jQuery to winform application? How?

Comment: For that you have to look into the embedding browser control in C#. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Hey Go through the Given link [RichTextBox Demo](http://nicedit.com/demos.php)

It's so Simple to integarte with your Application,If you are using Web based application.

The links contain Source code also.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks Man! But my application is winform.